# why does the face become weird or invisible when the color is changed?

Tags: color, color-management

I'm just learning Blender. I want to color some parts of the car that I have made. but when i change the assign to a new color the face of the object becomes weird and sometimes becomes invisible.

[image]

when I try it on a simple object like a cube this also happens.

[image]

can you help me?

Comment: Definitely not normal. Could be a GPU or OpenGL issue maybe. What does your setup look like (processor, GPU, operating system)? Regardless, make sure your graphics drivers are up to date (except maybe in the case of AMD GPU's whose drivers have caused blender trouble recently).

Comment: My setup is (processor: core i5, GPU: AMD Mobility HD 5770, OS: Windows 10). Thank you for information about AMD GPU's whose drivers have caused blender trouble. @Christopher Bennett

Comment: check face orientations maybe that is  causing  the issue. if not provide a blend file with those materials and a example model

Comment: Here the blend file [link](https://github.com/cerclematu/Blender/tree/c4ee480282294276ebaeacc7b185b35ecd8032df). may be you can help me @mma78

Comment: I can't see the transparent face here so yes it may be a driver problem, have you tried a previous one?

Comment: thanks for seeing it @moonboots . so now i know my GPU doesn't support or driver problem. The best way I can handle it is by duplicating the face of object into a single object and coloring it. The results are in the [link](https://github.com/cerclematu/Blender/blob/main/London-Cyberpunk-evee3.png) above. but I don't know if this method will work in the future.

Comment: what do you mean by "so now i know my GPU doesn't support or driver problem"? If you think it's a graphic card problem, maybe try to enable the High Quality Normals options in the Render panel > Performance?

Comment: I think so, because you don't see it transparently. I have enabled the High Quality Normals. try blender version 2.8 until the latest update 2.9xx. the result remains the same, the face of the object with 2 colors, one of the faces of the object will be transparent or be weird. @moonboots

Comment: I don't see the transparent  but I don't have a GPU also . I run blender on my intel . sry could't find the issue